Not able to access the context variable AuthContext in context provider component
Screenshot
Giving info message in vs code : Cannot find namespace 'AuthContext'
Here is my package.json file
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.11.4",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.11.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.15.20",
    "@mui/material": "^5.15.20",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.52.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.23.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.66",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.22",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.6",
    "typescript": "^5.2.2",
    "vite": "^5.2.0"
  }
}

Any problem in creating the context?

If you name the file with .tsx instead of .ts does the issue go away? In .ts files, angle brackets are interpreted as type assertions, not jsx elements

yes it works! when i changed the file extension
